# Is the set of the solutions $x+y-(2a^2+2a)|z|=a^3-a$ a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}$, determine whether the set of solutions of the equation

> $$x+y-(2a^2+2a)|z|=a^3-a$$

is a subspace in $\mathbb{R^3}$ or not. Justify.

Comment: It would be better is you write down your question here. That way discourage attention to the OP. Moreover you should discuss what you have tried and what are your doubts.

Comment: Try to follow the given hint and show your work here, we'll take a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let check the properties that a subspace has to fulfill.

Firstly check whether the solution $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is in the set that is

$$x+y-(2a^2+2a)|z|=a^3-a\implies a^3-a=a(a^2-1)=0 \implies a=0,\pm1$$